# How to wait for a page to load or element to be present when using Protractor for a non-Angular page

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am new to Protractor.  I think I have this down when dealing with an Angular page, but can't figure it out for a non-Angular page.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
describe('Search', function() {
   it('should click Search button and wait for results', function() {
      browser.driver.findElement(by.id('search')).click();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out.  I simply added the code below, after the click method:

```
describe('Search', function() {
   it('should click Search button and wait for results', function() {
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('search')).click();
        dvr.wait(function() {
            return dvr.isElementPresent(by.xpath(
                '/html/body/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span'));
        }, 20000);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's correct, using `browser.wait` helps. If you do this a lot you may find useful **Alternative 2** on my answer below.

Comment: I had to replace dvr.wait and dvr.isElementPresent with browser.wait and browser.isElementPresent to make it work

Answer (score 15):

Testing non-angular pages with Protractor can be tricky regarding waiting for stuff.

I suggest you upgrade Protractor to [latest](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases) (1.5.0 as of now), use a [custom function waitReady()](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb) that `browser.wait` for elements ready and rewrite your test like below. Note you can put everything within 1 spec if you like so.

```
// TODO: use page objects
var searchBtnElm = $('#search'); // use element(by.id('search')) if you prefer

it('waits for the elements present and visible (non-angular)', function() {
    expect(searchBtnElm.waitReady()).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should click Search button', function() {
    searchBtnElm.click();
});

it('wait for more results', function() {
    // keep using waitReady() before interacting with the elements
    // and before performing expectations on them
});
```

More details of why `waitReady` [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1557).

Note: remember to set ignore synchronization for testing a non-angular page:

```
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

You can set it before `browser.get` the non-angular page.

I've suggested setting a high implicit wait in the past, e.g.

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
```

That *hack* allows to you avoid `waitReady` and keep using the standard

```
expect(searchBtnElm.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

But has an ugly disadvantage when testing for elements **NOT** present, i.e. when testing for absent or non visible elements in which case it will wait 5 seconds (5000ms) in vane, e.g. when doing

```
expect(someNonExistingElm.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: great answer, maybe add that the onPrepare block is in the protractor config file. +1 anyway =)

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. See Julie's response here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1086 it seems that setting ignore synchronization to `true` will cause the browser driver to not wait implicitly, so you'll need to manually browswer.wait

Comment: Julie doesn't mention implicit wait in her comments there. Try to read more carefully, see @davidwparker was getting `Error: Locator cannot be empty` for an incorrect use of `isElementPresent`. When ignoreSynchronization is false this means Protractor won't wait for outstanding angular timing stuff however implicit wait is at webdriver level so is not affected by ignoreSynchronization value.

Comment: You need to incorporate a snippet, is not built-in Protractor by default. Snippet at https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb

Answer (score 1):

Another Neat approach is to use "Expected Conditions" inside browser.wait - something like this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var search = element(by.id('search'))
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(search), 2000).then(function(){
 search.click()
})
```

You can get more details here: https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions

Answer (score 1):

In protractor there are two types terms for on the page. `isPresent` ask if the element is exists on the page. `isDisplayed` asks if the element is visible. If you are waiting for a page to load you need to wait for `isDisplayed`, but that will error if it is not present, so wait for `isPresent` first. I use a function to wait for an element.

```
function waitForElement(el, waitTimeoutMilliseconds){
    return browser.wait(function() { return el.isPresent(); }, waitTimeoutMilliseconds)
        .then(function(){
           return browser.wait(function() { return el.isDisplayed(); }, waitTimeoutMilliseconds);
        });
}
```

Then just call that function in your test.

```
describe('Search', function() {
    it('should click Search button and wait for results', function() {
        var el = element(by.id('search'));
        waitForElement(el, 5000);
        el.click();
    });
});
```